# How to get particular muc room details from open fire using strophe

Tags: php, xmpp, strophe

How to get particular muc room details from open fire using strophe.for example code am tried below but am not get muc room details fully.

```
var iq = $iq({
        from: Groupie.JID,
        to: 'test@conference.test.com',
        type: "get"
    }).c("query", {
        xmlns: "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"
    });
```

How to get muc room details fully. any one knows reply me..

Comment: What are you not getting that you are looking for?